# bar plot with long list of information

Tags: ggplot2

Do you have any idea how can deal this kind of graph. I have long list of the information which should be visible and I have to make stacked graph.
How can I show the represent color? it could be animation or below the stacked graph,
any suggestion?thank you in ana advance
[ggplot with long list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Ko9.png)

Comment: How do you want to deal with the 76 colours? Do you want to show them all, or simplify/group them into fewer colours, or just not display the legend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier for us to help if you could share a sample of your data and any initial attempt to code a solution. Here's a little illustrative reproducible example of a stacked bar chart.

Please clarify how you would like to deal with the 76 colours. In this example I've suppressed the legend.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data_df <- tibble(group = c(rep("a", 38), rep("b", 38)),
                  value = abs(rnorm(76, 10, 10)),
                  fill = 1:76)

data_df |> 
  mutate(fill = factor(fill)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(group, value, fill = fill)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>